# Как перетаскивать цену мышкой?

Tags: javascript

Есть 2 ордера созданные через createPriceLine, добавил параметр draggable: true, но не срабатывает.

Напишите что еще не хватает, в документации ничего про это не нашел https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs

```js
const chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(document.body, {
  width: 400,
  height: 260,
});
const series = chart.addBarSeries({
  priceFormat: {
    minMove: 0.25,
  }
});
series.setData([
  { time: '2022-08-15', open: 60, high: 80, low: 50, close: 67 },
]);

series.createPriceLine({
  price: 75,
  color: 'rgba(229, 37, 69, 1)',
  lineWidth: 2,
  lineStyle: LightweightCharts.LineStyle.Dotted,
  title: 'sell order',
  draggable: true,
});

series.createPriceLine({
  price: 70,
  color: 'rgba(53, 162, 74, 1)',
  lineWidth: 2,
  lineStyle: LightweightCharts.LineStyle.Dotted,
  title: 'buy order',
  draggable: true,
});

chart.timeScale().fitContent();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lightweight-charts/dist/lightweight-charts.standalone.production.js"></script>
```

Еще дополнительно, как получить обратную связь после изменения цены, к примеру при изменении вызвать свою функцию?

Comment: а откуда ты взял опцию `draggable`? И что конкретно ты хочешь перетаскивать?

Comment: @Grundy взял отсюда https://jsfiddle.net/randalhsu/5un8r93g/ это все что нашел. Перетаскивать имеется виду двигать вних вверх, изменения цены мышкой. К примеру клик по 'sell order' зажать мышкой и двигать цену вниз или вверх, и при отжатии мышки вызвать функцию куда передать новую цену у этого ордера.

Comment: отнюдь, шкала расширяется мышкой, может draggable к этому и относится..

Comment: Сравни версию у себя и версию в jsfiddle. там используется дев сборка, и нужной функции просто нет ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ либо не добавили в релиз, либо уже убрали.